# First character not getting printed in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am learning to code in Kivy using python
But my Label is not showing the first character
Can anyone help me
The kv File is as follows:

```
<MyGrid>
    Label:
        text: "Techy Matanhelia"
```

The python file is as Follows:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Also Can anyone tell me how to edit kivy files on pycharm2020.2.2

Comment: Adding to the Above when i set the label to "Tech with tim" or something smaller than 15 characters the first Character gets printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `MyGrid` class extends `Widget`. A simple `Widget` has no capability to handle positioning or sizing of its children, so the `Label` gets assigned the default size of `(100,100)` and the default position of `(0,0)`. which results in the first letter of the `Label` being off the screen. Try making `MyGrid` extend a `Layout`, perhaps like this:

```
class MyGrid(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

Comment: But in the Video series the First Character is coming on the screen

Comment: I Learn from youtube and in those videos the character can be seen. Is it connected to screen resolution

Comment: Or is it related to my version of windows

Comment: for reference to the fact the it gets printed in the videoseries that I am learning from here is the link https://youtu.be/AS3b70pLYEU?list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kSJVMyYeOQ8CXJ3z1k7gHn&t=273